# Equality of two measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement. Let $F$ and $G$ be two finite measures on $((-\pi,\pi],\mathcal{B}((-\pi,\pi]))$ such that
$$\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}e^{ih\lambda}\,dF(\lambda)=\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}e^{ih\lambda}\,dG(\lambda) \quad \text{for every } h \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Then, $F = G$.

The only trick that I know in showing two measures to be equal is the so-called $\pi$-system argument. I don't see how it applies here. The hint in the question uses heavy functional-analytic arguments and those are a bit beyond my knowledge.

Can someone give a not necessarily complete but a tutorial-like proof of this fact?

Comment: The objects on the right- and left-hand sides are simply characteristic functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of random variables with distributions $F$ and $G$ respectively. Since the characteristic function uniquely defines the distribution (e.g. Fourier transform is invertible), distributions of these variables coincide.

Comment: @Vossler Wow I did not see that. Thanks. Why don't you post this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since I'm not sure if you need to prove the invertibility of the Fourier transform or you can use it as a known fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects on the right- and left-hand sides are simply [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) of random variables with distributions $F$ and $G$ respectively. Since the characteristic function uniquely defines the distribution (e.g. Fourier transform is invertible), distributions of these variables coincide.

Comment: I just realized now that $h$ is an integer. So there is a missing step I think.

Comment: @Calculon I don't think it changes the essence of the argument: from basic  Fourier series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) theory it follows that if a function is defined on a bounded interval (or periodic on $R$), it can be decomposed w.r.t. a countable basis (e. g. Fourier basis) in a given scalar product (integral w.r.t the measure in your case) and that this series decomposition is invertible. Your problem statement tells you precisely that all the expansion coefficients are equal.

Comment: @Calculon My Fourier series theory is pretty rusty so I don't think I will be able to formalise it completely, but I think the intuition (and what to search for if you want to) is pretty clear here. If you would still like to request an answer here, from what I've read in the meta the proper way would be to leave the previous edition of the question as it was and ask a new question.

Comment: No worries. thank you.